# Scaling image inside td tag?

Tags: html, css, image, height

I have a table containing nine td's, each of which should contain a different image.

So I have:

```
<td>
  <img src="pics/LLTR.jpg" class="lltr"></img>
</td>
```

and the css classes

```
.lltr:hover{
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.lltr{
    max-height:auto;
    max-width:100%;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s; /* Safari */
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

This is the current version. I've tried it as background-image and lots other stuff none of which worked properly.
The image obviously displays with the width of the td and the auto height, which causes the td to expand in height even though the table-layout has been set to fixed.

Is there a way to scale the image proportionally to the width without dislaying any "leftover" height, just like the cover property for background-images?

Thx,
Rawk

The entire code for the table:

```
<table id="maintab">
        <tr>
            <td class="isFixed">1</td>
            <td class="isFixed">2
            </td>
            <td class="isFixed">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="isLinked">
                <img src="pics/LLTR.jpg" class="lltr"></img>
            </td>
            <td class="isLinked">5</td>
            <td class="isLinked">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="isLinked">7</td>
            <td class="isLinked">8</td>
            <td class="isLinked">9</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

CSS part:

```
#maintab{
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 20px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

.lltr:hover{
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.lltr{
    max-height:auto;
    max-width:100%;
         /*background-image: url('pics/LLTR.jpg');
         background-size:cover;*/
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s; /* Safari */
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.isLinked{

}

.isLinked:hover{
    background-color:rgba(240,240,240,0.75);cursor:pointer;
}

.isFixed{
    background-color:rgba(197,197,197,0.6);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why background image as cover doesn't work?

Comment: Me neither, but setting the image as background-image as cover sets the image to its actual height (expanding the td) and cuts off the leftover width.

Comment: The table cell will expand in height to accommodate the content, the image in this case.  Are you specifying the height of the table?

Comment: I've specified the table size to 100vw and 100vh and set each td height to 33%.

Comment: How many rows are in the table, and columns? Can you post the code for the entire table? That would help.

Comment: Just added the code above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proof-of-concept that might work.

I set the height and width of the table cell (in my example, a 2x2 grid),
and then within each table cell I place a `div` with `overflow: hidden`.

I then set the width of the image to 100% and any excess height will be 
clipped by the `div` element.

I assumed that the image was a portrait type. In some cases, for large enough
screens, there may be enough space in the table to show the entire image.

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
  padding: 0;
}
td div {
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
td div img {
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<table cell-spacing=0>
  <tr>
    <td><div>one</div></td>
    <td><div>three</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div>two</div></td>
    <td><div><img src="https://picsum.photos/400/600/"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```